# Creating dynamically named mutators in Laravel Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, traits, mutators

I have a list of date fields, and all of them have the same logic in their mutators. I would like to extract this functionality to a trait so that in the future all I would need is to create an array of date fields in the model and use the trait.

Something like this:

```
foreach( $dates as $date ) {
    $dateCamelCase = $this->dashesToUpperCase($date);
    $setDateFunctionName ='set'.$dateCamelCase.'Attribute';
    $this->{$setDateFunctionName} = function()  use($date) {
        $this->attributes[$date] = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $date ));
    };
}
```

Comment: show some code, and your current attempts

Comment: added the way I tried

Comment: @shaswa Were you able to solve it? I am having a similar situation and trying the same. Please let me know if you could work it out.

Comment: @Donkarnash : I haven't been able to. Due to a time crunch, had to define a mutator for each of the fields in the Model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before answering your specific question, let's first see how Eloquent mutators work.

#### How eloquent mutators work

All Eloquent [`Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1385-L1388)-derived classes have their [`__set()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) and [`offsetSet()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php) methods to call the [`setAttribute`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L517-L549) method which takes care of setting the attribute value and mutating it, if needed.

Before setting the value, it checks for:

- Custom mutator methods
- Date fields
- JSON castables and fields

#### Tapping into the process

By understanding this, we can simply tap into the process and overload it with our own custom logic. Here's an implementation:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Concerns;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes;

trait MutatesDatesOrWhatever
{
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        // Custom mutation logic goes here before falling back to framework's 
        // implementation. 
        //
        // In your case, you need to check for date fields and mutate them 
        // as you wish. I assume you have put your date field names in the 
        // `$dates` model property and so we can utilize Laravel's own 
        // `isDateAttribute()` method here.
        //
        if ($value && $this->isDateAttribute($key)) {
            $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
        }

        // Handover the rest to Laravel's own setAttribute(), so that other
        // mutators will remain intact...
        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Needless to say that your models require to use this trait to enable the functionality.

#### You ain't gonna need it

If [mutating dates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) is the only usecase you need to have *"dynamically named mutators"*, that's not required at all. As you might have already [noticed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L532), Eloquent's date fields can be reformatted by Laravel itself:

```php
class Whatever extends Model 
{
    protected $dates = [
        'date_field_1', 
        'date_field_2', 
        // ...
    ];

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';
}
```

All fields listed there will be formatted as per `$dateFormat`. Let's not reinvent the wheel then.

Comment: In case one needs to reuse accessors/mutators, you might be interested in Eloquent Mutators https://github.com/topclaudy/eloquent-mutators

Comment: you can also define casts in your model, wich is short and elegant:

    protected $casts = [
        'your_field' => 'datetime:d/m/Y H:i:s',
    ];

Comment: Creating multiple dynamic mutator Traits will call model parent::setAttribute multiple times?