# How to store datetime when timezone is different from UTC (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

My app timezone is set to 'America/Montreal'.
I have a two datetime fields 'start' and 'end', each casted to datetime using laravel $casts property:

```
protected $casts = [
    'start' => 'datetime',
    'end' => 'datetime'
];
```

When I create an instance of my model with the following data:

```
MyModel::create(
                [
                    'start' => "2022-02-08T20:45:58.000Z", // UTC time  
                    'end' => "2022-02-08T20:45:58.000Z",
                ]
            );
```

The created model keeps the same time (20:45) but the timezone is set to America/Montreal:

```
 App\MyModel {#4799
     id: 44,
     created_at: "2022-02-08 15:49:02",
     updated_at: "2022-02-08 15:49:02",
     start: 2022-02-08 20:45:58,
     end: 2022-02-08 20:45:58,
   }
```

when I access the start and end attributes I get the same time but with America/Montreal timezone like this:

```
// accessing 'start' attribute of the instance I just created
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1644371158 {#4708
 date: 2022-02-08 20:45:58.0 America/Montreal (-05:00),
```

}

The only way I found to get it to work correctly is to manually setTimezone before saving:

```
    MyModel::create(
                [
                    'start' => Carbon::parse("2022-02-08T20:45:58.000Z")->setTimeZone(config('app.timezone')),, 
                    'end' => Carbon::parse("2022-02-08T20:45:58.000Z")->setTimeZone(config('app.timezone')),,
                ]
            );
```

which is, I think, repetitive, isn't setting the app timezone enough ? Is there any better way to do this ? I know that I'm supposed to set my app timezone to UTC (which is what I do usually) but this projet has already a lot of data with this timezone and I'm not sure how to convert it.
Thank you.

Comment: How about using a mutator on model: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah I did, but I would need to define one for every datetime attribute in every model, I hope that there is a better way to do this

Comment: I see, have you tried this `protected $dateFormat = 'U';` on your model, from the same docs page under date casting section, though I've not tried this myself, seems like what you need

Comment: If the above doesn't help, I would make use the a dynamic trait, so you don't have to do it manually, and the following SO answer does exactly that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48371850/4311336

Comment: The point of setting it as a datetime in `$casts` is so you can pass `DateTime` or `Carbon` objects, not strings. Also why do you say "the timezone is set to America/Montreal" when you clearly show the date as "2022-02-08 20:45:58.0 +00:00"?

Comment: @miken32 My bad, I've just correct the example. 
I'm not sure I understand what do you mean, I think that $casts are used so if you pass a string it's casted to a Datetime (mutator) and when you retrieve it from the database the string is casted to Datetime (accessor)

Comment: @AbdulRehman thank you but I don't think that "protected $dateFormat = 'U';" solves the problem. The SO answer is interesting though.

Comment: If you are passing a string, you may as well just pass a string the database understands, and not ask Laravel to cast it. The point of `$casts` is so you can do things like `$model->start = Carbon::now()` instead of `$model->start = '2022-02-09 12:43:42'`. The database doesn't store time zones, it will assume you're storing in whatever time zone it's configured for, which by default is your server's time zone.

Comment: That's the problem, it stores it without doing timezone conversion to the app timezone and then retrieves it as if it was the app timezone, which is clearly a bug imo

Answer (score 5):

Laravel will just store the date in the model doing `$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` which just uses the original hour/time of the date, but without preserving the timezone information.

Then when it retrieves it, because it's just a string with no timezone info, it will cast it to a carbon date with the app timezone (generally UTC)

This creates a disparity because you do not get the same value from the getter than the one you sent to the setter, if your date had a different timezone than the app

In simpler words, this is basically what happens

```php
Carbon\Carbon::parse(Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-11-08 00:00', 'America/Montreal')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'UTC');

Carbon\Carbon @1667865600 {#4115
   date: 2022-11-08 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00), // As you can see it is UTC,
  // which is ok because the database does not store the timezone information,
  // but the time is 2022-11-08 00:00 and should be 2022-11-08 05:00:00 in UTC
}

// This would yield the correct result
Carbon\Carbon::parse(Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-11-08 00:00', 'America/Montreal')->setTimezone('UTC')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'UTC');
```

This is a very controversial problem in laravel which doesn't have a sane and expected handling of dates in model, which should have been to convert to the app timezone before casting the date to a string without timezone info, it was marked as ["intended behavior"](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/43036#issuecomment-1185368274)

To palliate this, you can make your own model extension overriding the `setAttribute` method and extend from this class instead to convert all the dates automatically to your app timezone

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use DateTimeInterface;
use Carbon\CarbonInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class Model extends BaseModel
{

    /**
     * Set a given attribute on the model.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if ($value instanceof CarbonInterface) {
            // Convert all carbon dates to app timezone
            $value = $value->clone()->setTimezone(config('app.timezone'));
        } else if ($value instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
            // Convert all other dates to timestamps
            $value = $value->getTimestamp();
        }
        // They will be reconverted to a Carbon instance but with the correct timezone
        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to set your database timezone to your app timezone, otherwise if you store dates in `timestamp` instead of `datetime` you may get errors when trying to insert a date because the date may fall in a daylight saving time

In your `config/database.php`

```php
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            //...
            'timezone'  => '+00:00', // Should match app.timezone
            //...
```

If you didn't do that before, you will need to migrate all your dates, here is a migration that does just that

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ConvertAllTimestampsToUtc extends Migration {
    public static function getAllTimestampColumns(): array
    {
        $results = DB::select(
            "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns WHERE DATA_TYPE LIKE 'timestamp' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE :db_name", [
            'db_name' => DB::getDatabaseName()
        ]);

        return collect($results)->mapToGroups(fn($r) => [$r->TABLE_NAME => $r->COLUMN_NAME])->toArray();
    }

    public static function convertTzOfTableColumns($table, $columns, $from = '+00:00', $to = 'SYSTEM')
    {
        $q = array_map(fn($col) => "`$col` = CONVERT_TZ(`$col`, '$from', '$to')", $columns);
        DB::update("UPDATE `$table` SET " . join(', ', $q));
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        foreach (self::getAllTimestampColumns() as $table => $cols) {
            self::convertTzOfTableColumns($table, $cols);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        foreach (self::getAllTimestampColumns() as $table => $cols) {
            self::convertTzOfTableColumns($table, $cols, 'SYSTEM', '+00:00');
        }
    }
};
```